# Getting all the products in category

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel for a store project, I created the Models

**Model : Category.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    public function products(){
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

**Model : Product.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller : ProductController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function getAll($idCategory)
    {
        $roducts = Category::findOrFail($idCategory)->products();
    }
}
```

I got this error:

> Method 'findOrFail' not found in \App\Category

I have tried to solve this by changing to :

`$roducts = Category::query()->findOrFail($idCategory)->products();`

And I got this error:

> Method 'products' not found in \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|static|static[]

**UPDATE** 
I'm using Laravel 5.7.24, and the errors are from the IDE (PhpStorm).

Comment: What version of Laravel do you use ? You get this error in your IDE or in the webpage ?

Comment: Sorry; The error is in IDE, I'm using PhpStorm. laravel version is 5.7

Comment: You can use this package for better autocompletion for Laravel : https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper

Comment: still having the same problem, (i think i didn't really udstand the Readme in the repo and havn't set it up in the right way)